# Sencha Touch 2 android performance

Tags: javascript, android, extjs, webview, sencha-touch-2

I am hearing that sencha in general, by the mere fact of using javascript, has performance issues on android devices.

I am familiar with limitations of the android webview object, but I was wondering if these performance claims have any merit, especially with Sencha Touch 2 being out

Although I don't have a lower end android device, I was looking through the Sencha Touch 2 gallery and could not find free android apps very easily, so perhaps you can explain your experience with Sencha Touch 2 on Android and what you did to make it faster

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To my experience so far, there are some crucial points to keep in mind when developing Sencha Touch 2 applications with as best performance as possible:

1. To optimize application startup time:

   - Compress your JS & CSS files. Remove any unused JS functions or CSS mixins (this can be easily done through SASS/Compass). For more details, please read this: http://www.sencha.com/blog/an-introduction-to-theming-sencha-touch
   - Load external JS files dynamically, there's already a good topic here: [What is the proper way to load an external javascript in Sencha Touch 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334893/what-is-the-proper-way-to-load-an-external-javascript-in-sencha-touch-2)
2. To optimize application performance:

   - Keep your DOM structure as small as possible. Inactive views should be destroyed (and dynamically added to your Container later if needed).
   - Avoid using too many CSS3 properties since they are very slow on Android devices.
   - For any scrollviews, overscroll should be disabled on Android. I've tested many Sencha Touch 2 applications on Android devices and overscroll causes badly unpleasant experience because of delays and lags. (tested on Galaxy Tab, Nexus S, and some HTCs)

There's also a topic here which is quite relevant to your concern:

[PhoneGap 1.4 wrapping Sencha Touch 2.X - What about performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085637/phonegap-1-4-wrapping-sencha-touch-2-x-what-about-performance/10085756#10085756)

Hope it helps.

***edited on Feb, 12th 2014***: It has been nearly 2 years since I posted this answer (i.e. more than 3 years I have been working with Sencha Touch) and I have to say that Sencha Touch performance on Android is sadly unacceptable. Sometimes I was stuck in the thought that I'm not fully mastering the best practices, but I think it's not the reason. Or at least, it will took us years to develop a large-scale Sencha Touch app which has equal "look and feel" as native apps because the tricks take us so much time.

*So in shorts, if you are targetting iOS or your app is very tiny, it's okay. But for big apps on Android, I personally don't go with Sencha Touch.*

Comment: So what would make a good alternative for Sencha Touch in mobile web (given that native is not an option)?