# Sencha Touch - Peformance issue with senchatouch js size

Tags: performance, sencha-touch

I have build application using sencha touch, its all working fine except initial issue of initial loding time.
I have make its native app. using phonegap, have build its jsb3 file and app-all.js using that.
but its nothing to do with sencha-touch.js which has original size of about 2.4 M.B.
and its minified is also about 600 K.b. which is very large for mobile/tablet.

Is there anything like we can use sencha.js for only those component we are using in app ? or anyother way to reduce size or initial loading time?

Please provide me solution for this

Comment: Check out similar performance issues discussed here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338020/sencha-touch-2-android-performance & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085637/phonegap-1-4-wrapping-sencha-touch-2-x-what-about-performance/10085756#10085756

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i already try to follow as per your answer keeping my DOM as minimal as possible, dynamically handling viewes but i can't do much with sencha-touch.js except minified and compress and its creating initial loading problem

Comment: anyone can help me ?? still not found solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a native application with [Sencha SDK Tools](http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools).

If you have structured your project properly, you can use the following command to build your native application. This will also shrink your javascript size:

```
C:\wamp\www\SenchaApp>sencha app build -e native -d pkg/native -a archive
[INFO] Deploying your application to C:\wamp\www\SenchaApp\pkg\native
[INFO] Copied sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Copied app.js
[INFO] Copied resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Copied resources/images
[INFO] Copied resources/icons
[INFO] Copied resources/loading
[INFO] Copied resources/data
[INFO] Resolving your application dependencies...
[INFO] Found 18 dependencies. Concatenating all into app.js...
[INFO] Processed sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Minifying sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Processed app.js
[INFO] Minifying app.js
[INFO] Minifying resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Minified app.js
[INFO] Minified sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Minified resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Generated app.json
[INFO] Embedded microloader into index.html
[INFO] Packaging your application as a native app...
```

Comment: But i can say that performance is still an issue even if you minimize your code size. At least on Android...

Comment: Yes, its take 7-8 second to load on Android