# How to optimize Sencha Touch 2.0 performance on iPad?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am trying to optimize the performance of a [Sencha Touch 2.0](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/) app on iPad device.
Please point out some way for doing this.

Is any tools are available for iPad to test the performance of web app??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, this link may help:

[PhoneGap 1.4 wrapping Sencha Touch 2.X - What about performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085637/phonegap-1-4-wrapping-sencha-touch-2-x-what-about-performance/10085756#10085756)

About performance inspection, you can just use Developer Tools of your iPad's Safari. Here is a good tutorial to get started: https://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to deploy the app as an iPad native or are you going to use it within the web browser?

Whatever the case, if you are going to deploy as native, it will automatically be optimised and no unnecessary files will be loaded.

If you are going to use it within a web browser, I suggest deploying it as production and not loading the whole source.

This can be achieved by navigating to your sencha touch 2 app and running the following sdk command:

```
sencha app build production
```

Then you should load that page within your browser.