# Sencha app is too slow on IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, performance, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i have written a somewhat small application , yet it runs very slowly on IOS and Android devices , it seems to me that the device takes much time to render the GUI.

i made sure to require every component needed on launch time, my application consists of 5 tab panels , each one contains a navigation view with multiple panels , i have set the autoDestroy property of navigation views to true.

i used sencha 2.0.0.0 and 2.0.1.1 and phone gap cordova 1.7.0 , cordova 1.8.0

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

> i made sure to require every component needed on launch time

Because this, your application launches slow. The main reason is all of your elements are added to DOM tree right at startup time (you can inspect your application's DOM tree by Chrome's debugger tool to see it).

The best practice to optimize responsiveness of your application is discussed somewhere, here's one of them:

[PhoneGap 1.4 wrapping Sencha Touch 2.X - What about performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085637/phonegap-1-4-wrapping-sencha-touch-2-x-what-about-performance/10085756#10085756)

For your situation, a better way to implement is:

1. Divide your application into 2 main views, an `Ext.TabBar` and an `Ext.Container`
2. Listen to changes in TabBar clicks, if user changes from a tab to another, remove your view in the main container and add appropriate views. It ensures **your application only contains exactly 2 views** at any time.

Hope it helps.